# scrollbar iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, scrollbar

I would like to add a scrollbar when the contents of the iframe is too large and does not appear.

I am trying the following:

parent.iframepage.style.height = "350px";       
        parent.iframepage.style.width = "500px";
                parent.iframepage.contentarea.style.height = "350px";
            parent.iframepage.contentarea.style.width = "500px";
        parent.iframepage.contentarea.style.overflow = "visible";

any help please?

Comment: Try parent.iframepage.contentarea.style.overflow = "auto"

Comment: no, doesnt work unfortunately :(

Comment: Wait a second - you have a Main Page and an IFrame Page. Are you writing this in the IFrame Page or the Main Page? You'll need to set overflow=visible on the Main Page, and you won't be able to do that from the IFrame Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the correct syntax would be ...

```
parent.iframepage.style.overflow = "auto";
```

I'd recommend doing it in the stylesheet.

```
iframe
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You should qualify it better, with an ID, class or such.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the content of the iframe only if it is from the same domain as the parent document.